# how to make a mac vpn specific to some traffic？

Tags: mac, vpn

I use VPN on my Mac-mini to make some traffic more secure, but then I realized I can not access my computer as I want. typically, services like airplay or remote access through http port 80 stops responding. the traffic I am securibg is specific to an application, and it can be restricted to a specific port. so is there a way to set up the VPN so it only sends this traffic through itself, rather than everything?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of connecting to the remote VPN end via SSH you can create SSH tunnels on the specific application port (directing them to localhost:destination_port).  This method will encrypt the app's traffic while leaving your LAN connection untouched.